# Intuition behind Cauchy's Formula for a Disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Book: Complex Analysis in One Variable (Second Edition)

Authors: Raghavan Narasimhan and Yves Nievergelt

Page: 30

[Screenshot from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr3LW.png)

I have been thinking about this theorem but I do not understand its proof (I cannot visualize it).

The part I don't understand is its reparameterization, what is the intuitive idea behind it? Is there any geometrical interpretation?

I quote:

> Reparametrizing *(sic)* $\gamma$ in the form $\tau \mapsto w+\rho (\tau )e^{2\pi i\tau}\space (0\le \tau \le 1)$ as in the
> proof of §.1.2, Lemma 5 $(w \in D(a,r))$, we find, again as in the proof just cited, that $\int_{\gamma}{\frac{dz}{z-w}}$ for $w \in D(a,r)$, and the theorem follows.

What I don't understand is the composition of functions. There is a $\gamma$ (function) that is the reparameterization of the disk with center $a$ and a constant radius $r$. However, the reparameterization has as center $w$ and its radius varies (i.e.: it is not constant, or at least it seems so). And according to the definition of reparameterization, there must be a surjective and increasing function that at the moment of composing it with $\gamma$, should give me such reparameterization. My problem lies in finding such a surjective and increasing function, whose domain and range are $[0,1]$.